# How does IgnoreNulls ValidationAttribute affect other attributes Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Validation

Tags: c#, validation, .net-core, attributes, code-migration

I'm converting a legacy app from using Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibary.Validation to System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations, and I'm trying to figure out how to implement an IgnoreNulls attribute.  The old code has this:

```
    [IgnoreNulls]
    [StringLengthValidator(0, 255)]
    public string Description { get; set; }
```

According to the documentation the StringLengthValidator will not get called if Description is assigned null.  I'm trying to figure out how to do something similar.  Is there a way to "short circuit" out of the validation chain or a way for the StringLengthValidator attribute to know that the IgnoreNulls attribute exists on the property?

Comment: You could fairly easily create your own validator if push comes to shove - tons of examples out there

Comment: I am writing my own, but I'm trying to avoid sifting through thousands of lines of code to find and replace all of these.